# Debugger agent is not enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm debugging a Cordova TypeScript project with Ripple.  When I debug (Debug > Android > Ripple), the debug output window does not display debug messages.  Instead, I get the following message:
`code: -32000
 message: Debugger agent is not enabled`

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Chrome, Ripple or VS2015.

Windows 8.1, VS2015 RTM.

Comment: Having that same problem. I wonder if this is the culpright for the hot deploy not working for me (changing a .js file on VS is not reflecting on Ripple)

Answer (score 4):

You may find that what you're actually looking for

`Debug > Windows > JavaScript Console`

Comment: Yes, the JavaScript Console will display JavaScript console.... [see image](http://i.gyazo.com/8ab28a7ca231a7b877bad3051a8267a1.png).  I was hoping Output > Debug would do the same and more.  Instead, there's a code and message.  The message doesn't provide a lot of information.

Comment: It shows `console.log()` etc, is that not what you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the option of `Tools/Options/Debugging/’Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)` was disabled.

Just checked the box, restarted VS and was working.

This post was the helper: [Debugging JavaScript/TypeScript Using Visual Studio 2017 and Chrome or Edge](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2017/04/11/debugging-javascripttypescript-using-visual-studio-2017-and-chrome/)