# Visual Studio message "Debugger agent is not enabled" with Java Script

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2017 for JavaScript. But when I try to run with F5 I get "Debugger agent is not enabled". I have read some solutions on SO but none seem to work and some don't apply.

Can someone help me get over this error?

Comment: Save us all some time by helping us not repeat what you've already tried. 
 What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: I tried these "solutions":
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813562/debugger-agent-is-not-enabled
2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167051/debugger-agent-is-not-enabled-ionic-2-app-with-visual-studio-2015
3.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106297/typescript-vs2017-stops-at-first-line-error-debugger-agent-is-not-enabled

Comment: #2 doesn't even have an answer.  Okay, and what happened when you tried #1?  *What* answer did you try?  *Be specific*, don't just link to other questions on SO and expect that answers anything.  Put a little effort into your question.  If the only information you can provide us is "i tried that and it didn't work", that isn't informative.

Comment: I was hoping someone had run into this too and would have a good answer.
To be more specific, non of the hits gave proper information on the issue.

Comment: I gave the hits I found but none of them addressed my issue. You wanted to know what research I did and I gave that to you.
There is probably a setting someplace, like in Chrome or Visual Studio, that I have not been able to find.
Please help and don't criticize.

Comment: @eddyq Asking for additional information *is* helping, and you are not free from criticism.  Sorry, that isn't how this works.  Why do you have two accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me: Option 2: Install the Chrome Extension NIM (Node Inspector Manager): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj

Here is more information: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/